# Why drupal includes *.profile file on every page?

Tags: 7, distributions

I developed an installation profile that contains many various hooks. After an installation process, it is still included on every page, and all my installation hooks are executed. Please explain me why it happens, and by which way I can avoid including *.profile file after the installation.

Comment: I suspect that if you rename the files on the server that you will see errors in the logs.  This should pinpoint where the include is happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a new feature of Drupal 7: install profiles behave like modules.

See [#509398 : Install profiles should be modules with full access to the Drupal API and all it entails](http://drupal.org/node/509398)

Code that you don't want loaded during run-time should be moved to hook_install().

Edit - Xio asked about uninstalling a profile.
variable_set('profile', 'standard');
might work.

Comment: If install profiles behave like modules there must be some way to uninstall them. [drupal_uninstall_modules](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--install.inc/function/drupal_uninstall_modules/7) doesn't work with profiles.

Comment: variable_set('profile', 'standard'); doesn't work for me. Probably I need remove profile from system table.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal will not include installation files after installation by default.

The best reason I can give to this problem, would be some custom code toy have made includes the files. With the limited information you have provided it's hard to answer with more detail.

**Update**
If you want to "uninstall" a drupal install profile, this can be done by deleting the `install_profile` variable:

```
variable_del('install_profile')
```

You should be aware that doing this will not allow you to use modules located in your install profile folder like you normally can when using install profiles.

Comment: I have several theme and preprocess functions in *.profile* file. It doesn't work in *.install* file.

Comment: It works only in *.profile* file but don't in other files.